# ADT - constructor and type -- function accepting only one of the constructors

Tags: haskell

I wrote the [hsexif](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsexif) library and I would now add a feature, but I'm not sure how to prepare the API.

I have the [ExifValue](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsexif-0.5.0.0/docs/Graphics-HsExif.html#t%3aExifValue) type. A ExifValue can be among others a ExifRational, which has a numerator and a denominator. Often you want to display that value (show) as "num/den", for instance for an exposition time of 1/160.
However sometimes you want to show it as a floating-point number, for instance for the exposure compensation, which you would display as "-0.75" for instance, or the aperture ("6.3").

So I want to add a function:

```
formatAsFloatingPoint :: ExifValue -> Int -> String
```

The function takes the exif value and the number of floating points after the comma to output in the result string, and returns the formatted string.

However the function will then accept any ExifValue and the user will get a runtime error and no compile time warning if it gives a ExifText as a parameter to that function...

How would I go to make a clean and type-safe API in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to think about how you expect this to be used.

The caller might always know they have an `ExifRational` and will only call `formatAsFloatingPoint` with such a value. In that case it would make sense to refactor your datatype:

```
data Rational = Rational !Int !Int

data ExifValue = ... | ExifRational Rational | ...
```

(or perhaps reuse some existing type for expressing rationals)

and then make `formatAsFloatingPoint` take a `Rational`:

```
formatAsFloatingPoint :: Rational -> Int -> String
```

This moves the responsibility to the caller to decide when to call it.

Alternatively, perhaps callers just want to display an arbitrary `ExifValue`, but with special behaviour if the value happens to be an `ExifRational`. In that case, just use a catch-all case, e.g.:

```
formatAsFloatingPoint :: ExifValue -> Int -> String
formatAsFloatingPoint n (ExifRational num den) = ...
formatAsFloatingPoint _ v = show v
```

There are more complicated approaches based on using a type parameter to flag what kind of thing you have, but that would involve refactoring the entire library and there's little evidence that's warranted here. If you have a more general problem across the codebase of wanting to signal that you have specific kinds of `ExifValue`, they might make sense.

Comment: Yes, now that you put it that way, the first option is probably the right way forward.. Even more so because I have another constructor ``ExifRationalList ![(Int,Int)]``, which could become ``ExifRationalList [Rational]``. It maybe makes the user code a little bit more verbose though. Need to think about it a little bit.

Comment: `ExifRationalList` might also be an argument for the second option - you could have another case in the definition that recognises it and formats the entire list as floating point.

Comment: In EXIF a rational list would occur for instance for GPS coordinates. I don't think printing out a rational list to string is a common use case, the user code would have special requirements I think. A way to print out the base type and let you handle the composite case is more sensible I think.

Comment: Well, maybe I'll go for the second option because the function is not really something that you'd do every day and maybe wrapping the type just for that purpose is excessive. Also there is sense in the second solution for the other reasons you mentioned. I think I'll go for the second solution. Thanks!